# React.js: onSubmit Function passed from parent component to child component not getting called in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component A with a form which contains a configurable section with a child component B. I am trying to pass props to the child, one is a string called visitUuid which gets updated when a visit is created successfully and the handleSubmit event which is called on submitting the parent component and should be used to handle submitting the child component values to a different api. I can see my visitUuid prop but the handleSubmit does not submit values in the child component. On logging it, i can see its contents ie the values and validations in it. Any advise or useful links on how to use one submit handler for a parent and child will be appreciated.

My Parent Component :

```
interface VisitFormProps {
  patientUuid: string;
  closePanel: () => void;
}
const StartVisitForm: React.FC<VisitFormProps> = ({ patientUuid, closePanel }) => {
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const payload: NewVisitPayload = {};
      const abortController = new AbortController();
      saveVisit(payload, abortController)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            if (response.status === 201) { setVisitUuid(response.data.uuid); showToast(); }
          },
          (error) => { showNotification() },
        );
    },
    [],
  );
  const patientState = useMemo(
    () => ({ patientUuid, visitUuid, handleSubmit }),
    [patientUuid, visitUuid, handleSubmit],
  );
  const handleOnChange = () => {
    setIgnoreChanges((prevState) => !prevState);
  };
  return (
    <Form className={styles.form} onChange={handleOnChange}>
      <div>
        <TextInput
          className={styles.input}
          id="middleName"
          labelText={t('middleName', 'Middle name')}
          onChange={(event) => setMiddleName(event.target.value)}
          value={middleName}
        />
        <ExtensionSlot className={styles.content} extensionSlotName="add-queue-entry-slot" state={patientState} /> // child component StartVisitQueueFields
      </div>
      <Button onClick={handleSubmit} className={styles.button} kind="primary" type="submit">
        {t('startVisit', 'Start visit')}
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default StartVisitForm;
```

My Child Component:

```
interface StartVisitQueueFieldsProps {
  patientUuid: string;
  visitUuid: string;
  handleSubmit: (event) => void;
}
const StartVisitQueueFields: React.FC<StartVisitQueueFieldsProps> = ({ patientUuid, visitUuid, handleSubmit }) => {
  // to add queue entry if visit is not empty
  // check visit form event
  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const queuePayload: QueueEntryPayload = {};
    console.log("im almost submitting!")
    if (visitUuid !== undefined) {
      console.log('im here', visitUuid);
      saveQueueEntry(queuePayload, abortController)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            if (response.status === 201) { showToast();}
          },
          (error) => { showNotification();},
        );
    }
  };
  return (
    <Form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <section className={styles.section}>
        <div className={styles.sectionTitle}>{t('queueLocation', 'Queue Location')}</div>
          <Layer>
            <Select
              labelText={t('selectQueueLocation', 'Select a queue location')}
              id="location"
              invalidText="Required"
              value={selectedQueueLocation}
              onChange={(event) => setSelectedQueueLocation(event.target.value)}>
            </Select>
          </Layer>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default StartVisitQueueFields;
```

Comment: In the code you provided it doesn't seem like your parent component is rendering your child component. Where is the part where you are rendering `<StartVisitQueueFields/>` and passing props to it?

Comment: ```<ExtensionSlot className={styles.content} extensionSlotName="add-queue-entry-slot" state={patientState} />``` /This is my child component, i am using microfrontends. The ```patientState``` is where i pass the props

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the issue is that you don't have anything which triggers the `onSubmit` on your child component.
In order for `onSubmit` to be called on a form you need to have some kind of element (usually a button) with `type="submit"` which should be clicked inside the form.

If I understand your use case correctly, it seems like your child component shouldn't even be a form, because it looks like it acts as section in the parent form. Turn it into a regular div and then you have 2 options:

- [Lift the child component's state up to the parent component](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and include its `handleSubmit` logic to the parent's `handleSubmit`.
- Make the parent's component submit button of `type="submit"` and trigger the parent's form `handleSubmit` on the form `onSubmit` instead of the button `onClick`:

```
  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
   // you should be able to see all the fields and their values of your form on the `evt.currentTarget` object - make sure the form field elements have "name" and "id" attributes on them

    }

  ... 
 return (<Form className={styles.form} onChange={handleOnChange} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <TextInput
          className={styles.input}
          id="middleName"
          name="middleName"
          labelText={t('middleName', 'Middle name')}
          onChange={(event) => setMiddleName(event.target.value)}
          value={middleName}
        />
        <ExtensionSlot className={styles.content} extensionSlotName="add-queue-entry-slot" state={patientState} /> // child component StartVisitQueueFields
      </div>
      <Button className={styles.button} kind="primary" type="submit">
        {t('startVisit', 'Start visit')}
      </Button>
    </Form>)
```

then, make sure your child component isn't also a form and include an id and a name on its fields and you should see their values included in the parent's `onSubmit` event:

```
<div className={styles.form}>
      <section className={styles.section}>
        <div className={styles.sectionTitle}>{t('queueLocation', 'Queue Location')}</div>
          <Layer>
            <Select
              labelText={t('selectQueueLocation', 'Select a queue location')}
              id="location"
              name="location"
              invalidText="Required"
              value={selectedQueueLocation}
              onChange={(event) => setSelectedQueueLocation(event.target.value)}>
            </Select>
          </Layer>
    </div>
```